# AWK Command to Find the extension Issue

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am using the awk command to get the file extension in my script, however it's failing with one scenario which I need some advise..

Here are the two input files in my "Search_directory".. My Awk command is able to work for the file 1, it fails saying "The source line number is 1.
awk: 0602-533 Cannot find or open file".. What am I missing. Pls suggest. tnx!

```
File 1: hm101i.39.TF010J.TXT
File 2 : hm101i.39.TF010 JUNK.TXT


for file in "$SEARCH_DIR"/*; do
 extn=$(echo $file | awk -F '.' '{print $NF}')
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need awk for this, use bash's `${parameter##word}` expansion feature instead. like:

```sh
ext=${file##*.}
```

this simply removes the longest substring in `$file` matching `*.` which is a glob pattern.

```
file='hm101i.39.TF010J.TXT'
$ echo ${file##*.}
TXT
```

Comment: zsh version for those of us who prefer it over bash: `ext=${file:e}`